Geometry - determine whether an arc is collinear within a tolerance
Being new in this forum, can you help? My background is piles of math principles many years ago, now only programming.
Why is this important? Collinear definition: three points defining the arc are collinear, meaning they lie on a straight line rather than forming a curve. Notice: for Spatial GIS databases that is often not allowed. So checking up front of collinear arc is in some cases necessary.
Scanning the internet, there are $2$ commonly used algorithms to determine whether an arc is collinear within a tolerance. One with slopes and one with areas. Notice: to be sure: with tolerance I mean: the midpoint of the arc has a distance (within the tolerance) to the line from start and end coordinates of the arc.
The used algoritms are not correct when the middle point is not exactly in the middle between the start and end coordinates of the arc.
A good way of determining whether an arc is collinear is to actually calculate the center of the circle through the $3$ coordinates, then determining the midpoint of the arc and then calculating the distance between that midpoint and the line (from start to end coordinates). OK, that works, but it's not a cheap operation.
What is the best and cheapest way to determine whether the arc is collinear? Is there a better algorithm than the one above? I hope the algorithm looks like Java ;-)

What do you mean by an arc is collinear?

Collinear definition - three points defining the arc are collinear, meaning they lie on a straight line rather than forming a curve. For Spatial GIS databases, that is often not allowed.

Ah... and how is your arc (also please define this) given as an input for the procedure?

As 3 coordinates (x,y) and a tolerance.

Simple example: (1,1), (2,3), (4,1).

So the arc is circular and is specified by three points on the arc, two of which are specified to be endpoints of the arc? And the tolerance is an input to your algorithm but is not part of the definition of the arc itself?

My interpretation is: We are given three points. These three points define an arc of a circle (unless they are precisely colinear, in which case we are done). Let $h$ be the distance from the midpoint of the arc to the midpoint of a line through its end-points. If $h$ is less than a certain threshold, we treat the three points as colinear. (It might be more reasonable to look at the ration $h/d$, where $d$ is the distance between the end-points; the choice will depend on the needs of your application.)

How is the tolerance given? Or is it up to you to get a good criteria? I would use dot product instead.

If the tolerance is a fixed distance $h$, and the two endpoints of your arc have distance less than $2h$ between them, a semicircular arc would still be within the tolerance $h$. But maybe you don't mind replacing that arc with a straight line. If the tolerance is a ratio $h/d$ (where $d$ is the distance between endpoints, as suggested in a previous comment), I think I can give you an algorithm that uses only multiplication and addition. If it really is just a fixed distance $h$ it's a little more complicated. You can clear this up by editing the question, which could also help reopen it.

Let the three points be $A,B,C$, where $B$ is the mid-point. Calculating the position of the centre $O$ is just a matter of findding where the perpendicular bisectors of $AB$ and $BC$ cross. A little algebra is all you need.
And I suspect that you don't really want to know the distance between the midpoints of the arc $ABC$ and the line $AC$; you want a measure of the ratio between this distance and the distance $AC$, because this is independent of your units of length. And this ratio depends only on the ratio $AC/OA$. The actual form of this dependency is not important, because you are only interested in whether or not it exceeds a certain tolerance $T$. And you can experiment with various values of $T$ until you find one that meets the needs of your application.
